# In SQLite3, is there a foreignkey integrity check?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, pragma

My `foreign_key` constraint was not working when I was able to delete a parent entry.  The pragma for `foreign_key` is `off` by default for each session.  Seems odd there isn't a resource file (like .exrc for vi) to setup pragmas by default for each session.  So I have to recompile SQLite3 or just set it every time.

After I delete the parent, how do I do an integrity check on foreign key constraints?  I.e. tell SQLite to run the same logic it runs when it does it originally if you had the pragma turned on at the time of the insert or delete etc.?

I see a pragma `integrity_check` but that's just looking for corruption.

Comment: ooops!  I just learned from here [link](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/tool/)  there IS a .sqliterc you can put in your home dir.  That is exactly what I wanted.  Just put in the line "pragma foreign_keys=on;" and I'm all set.

Answer (score 19):

Beginning with SQLite 3.7.16, there is [PRAGMA foreign_key_check](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_check).

Answer (score 12):

Run the following command:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys;
```

Result will be:

```
0 // foreign keys Disabled
1 // foreign keys Enabled
```

To enable or disable foreign keys run:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

or

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
```

More information [Here](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)